# ASP.NET Core facebook login correlation failed

Tags: asp.net, facebook, asp.net-core

I am trying to implement facebook login to my ASP.NET Core project, but I receive correlation failed exception.[This is the exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjZlK.jpg)

[This is my StartUp.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxQvU.jpg)
[And my implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Q2sL.jpg)

Comment: First of all: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: What version of .net core are you using? You can read this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/facebook-logins?view=aspnetcore-3.1